# How to deal with a project where debugging is not possible?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, microservices, software-design

I have joined a new project recently and realized the debugging is impossible or not enabled. It's very difficult for me to work since the whole code has weird(finance) terminology, so reading the code is also very difficult.

But everyone on the team has spent almost a decade on the project and I am new so facing the problem of understanding the code. I don't understand how people keep on saying "Read the code".

I believed that reading the code is "sin" and the only way through is either debugging or playing around the changes.

I want to know the experienced people's perspective on how to work on such a project as a developer. Any suggestion to go forward?

Comment: Read the code. Make notes. Make a start on writing the 'system logic manual' that does not now exist. Dicking around in a debugger is just trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

You have not yet mentioned why debugging would not work. Here are some things that you can do on top:

- To better understand the code, start adding [JavaDoc comments](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/javadoc/javadoc.html#GUID-7A344353-3BBF-45C4-8B28-15025DDCC643).
- Add [unit tests](https://junit.org/) to ensure some methods do what they are expected to do.
- Add [logging](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/index.html) that you can use while developing and deactivate by configuraton in production environments.

This may mean you touch code that you are expected to only read, so your team can react annoyed.